# Exact Search Term in Elastic Search in Kibana Dev Tools (with ES 5.x)

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, kibana, elasticsearch-5

I have setup Elastic Search 5.x & Kibana on my local development environment, and have setup the indices I want to have results return exact search term (so only return results where that exact search term/string is found.

How can I adjust this to perform an exact search so "facebook advice" would be valid, but "advice facebook" would not be found

My existing Kibana query is as follows :

```
{
  "query": {
     "bool": {
        "should": [
         {
           "match": {
           "text": "facebook advice"
         }
       },
      {
      "match": {
        "profile": "facebook advice"
      }
    }
  ],
  "minimum_should_match": 1,
  "filter": {
    "term": {
      "accountid": "15"
    }
   }
  }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You would need to form your query within double quotes for exact match in Kibana.

E.g. "facebook advice"

Kibana would of course escape the quotes correctly under the hood.

Comment: This is obviously not true. Syntax error. Unexpected `'''`